# HTML5 Video does not work with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: windows-10, video, internet-explorer, html5

I have recently formatted my computer and installed a clean version of Windows 10 Pro N and HTML5 Video tags are not working.

I have tried to install the Media Features pack KB3010081 and KB3099229 but this does not fix the problem.

I have heard that installed Windows Media Player may help fix the problem, but I cannot run, download or install it. I have looked in optional features and have found nothing even after installing the media pack and restarting a number of times.

Does anyone have a fix for this?

Comment: As you installed a N version of Windows you're lacking the Media Player on purpose.

Comment: Fair enough, but i still need to get HTML5 Video Elements working. I have tried manually installing media player using the two KB packages mentioned above but this has not helped. I only suspect that installing WMP would help get the HTML5 VIdeo Elements working as I do not know what else might work.

Comment: What's the format of the video? What happened during/after the installation of the media pack? Did you try to find the media player on your machine afterwards? What is the format of the video you're trying to play back using HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

- Update your Internet Explorer.
- Test the video in Compatibility View.
- Make sure that add-ons are installed and enabled
  -On the Tools menu in Internet Explorer, click Internet Options.
  -Click the Programs tab, and then click Manage add-ons.
  -In the Currently loaded add-ons list, click Run without Permissions.
  -Look for the following add-ons in the list that's displayed. If any of these add-ons
  are listed, make sure the Status for each is listed as Enabled

  - Shockwave Active X Control
  - Shockwave Flash Object
  - Java Plug-in (may be multiple add-ons)
  - QuickTime Plug-in (may be multiple add-ons)
  - Windows Media Player.
- Update to the latest add-ons